# Restore backup of SQL Server database results in an error

Tags: sql-server, restore

I want to restore my backup that I get it before has no extension.

It's filename is:

```
mssdp-dd-dump-75b5264f8e294595b462ec13a212f225
```

that has no extension; I don't know how to change extension to `.bak` or ...

When I right click on database and click restore database and select source this file causes an error when I used:

```
RESTORE DATABASE test 
FROM DISK = 'c:\users\user\desktop\pmm-mssdp-dd-dump-75b5264f8e294595b462ec13a212f225'
```

I get this error:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
> The media family on device 'c:\users\user\desktop\pmm-mssdp-dd-dump-75b5264f8e294595b462ec13a212f225' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: This is not really a question on programming, you should probably ask over on Stack Exchange. Saying that, the top result for your error from Google is this [The media family on device is incorrectly formed](https://sqlbak.com/blog/media-family-on-device-is-incorrectly-formed)

Comment: I don't think that's a proper backup file from an SQL Server instance, it looks like a file system backup from a Plesk server (i.e.: using the `dd` tool to backup an entire volume or partition).

Comment: the database that i get backup was deleted and i cant backup again this backup can't be use? @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Please [edit] the question and explain how exactly the backup was taken. Mention any tools, software and commands used. If you don't know, ask the person who's responsible for backups.

Comment: Someone gave you that file. Ask that person exactly what that file contains and how it was generated (and even how to use it). Guessing is not going to be an efficient or effective way to address your issue.

Comment: As everyone else has mentioned, this is not a native SQL Server Backup file, and therefore you won't be able to directly restore it with **SSMS**. It appears it *may* be a Plesk database backup, and if so, then maybe [these Plesk restore instructions](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213904125-How-to-back-up-restore-a-system-database-in-Plesk) will be of help. Please verify the source of what created that backup file.

Comment: I would also gently suggest that if you don't know how to change a file extension, you should probably leave the whole restore operation to someone more experienced

Comment: `RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK` command will confirm if the backup set is valid and complete. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-verifyonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15